# SONY SPRESENSE Bluetooth LE Add-onボード SPRESENSE-BLE-EVK-701 で独自のService, Characteristicでアドバタイズしたい

Tags: spresense, arduino, bluetooth

[SPRESENSE Bluetooth®LE Add-onボード SPRESENSE-BLE-EVK-701](https://www.rohm.co.jp/support/spresense-add-on-board) を購入しました。

このアドオンボードに搭載されているBLEモジュールの資料

- [MK71251-02ユーザーズ・マニュアル](http://www.lapis-semi.com/jp/data/user's%20manual-file_db/telecom/FJUK71251-02-01.pdf)
- MK71251-02A用ATコマンド・アプリケーションユーザーズ・マニュアル
- MK71251-02A ATコマンド仕様書

を参照したのですが、[MK71251-02ユーザーズ・マニュアル](http://www.lapis-semi.com/jp/data/user's%20manual-file_db/telecom/FJUK71251-02-01.pdf)4章「コマンド・インタフェース」のように、このモジュールにはHCIコマンドとATコマンドの2種類のインターフェースがあります。

ATコマンド・アプリケーションユーザーズ・マニュアル 4.2.1節にあるように、
https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/Arduino/tree/master/MK71251-02
にあるサンプルでは、「アプリケーションモード（Add-onタイプ）」で動かしていて、サービスやキャラクタリスティックがラピス独自のもので固定 (VSSPP, VSA) かと思われます。
ATコマンドで、ユーザー自身でサービスやキャラクタリスティックを追加するには、付属の Windows アプリケーションから、EEPROM の GATT_DB テーブルを修正する必要があるということでしょうか。
またサンプルでは "ATS150=" で始まるコマンドで、Sレジスタの150番のアドバタイズデータを書き換えていることは分かりますが、そのコマンドの仕様が分かりません。キャラクタリスティックの値を書き換えるときは "ATS150=" で始まるコマンドで書き換えるのでしょうか？

HCIコマンドの場合、OGFとOCFからなるコマンドにて、SPRESENSEからUARTで操作できるのかなと思われますが、コマンドの仕様や、アドバタイズ・接続までの具体的な手順が不明でした。

SPRESENSEで Bluetooth LE Add-onボード SPRESENSE-BLE-EVK-701 を用い、独自のService, Characteristicでアドバタイズし、Value を自由に書き換えたいと思っておりまして、もしそのようなArduino サンプルがあれば非常に助かります。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

お使いのBLEモジュールは、仰る通り、ATコマンド・アプリケーションが動作します。
このアプリケーションに、サービスやキャラクタリスティックをユーザーにて追加して動作する
構成とはなっておりません。但し、DIS(Device Information Service)の各キャラクタリスティックに
関しては、Windowsツール(GATT_DBテーブル生成ユーティリティ)で、修正・削除することが出来ます。

“ATS150=”で始まるコマンドは、アドバタイズ・データ変更のためのコマンドです。
キャラクタリスティックの変更は出来ません。
Bluetooth仕様で規定されたフォーマット(詳細はBluetooth SIGのHPを参照して下さい)で指定することで、
送信されるアドバタイズ・データを変更することが出来ます。